# ConvertRect doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, converters

I'm trying to convert deep 'Subview' frame to an upper 'UIView'. I'm attaching the view hierarchy here.

Attaching illustration:

[image]

I've tried this, but the result are way off screen :

```
let rect = smallSubview.convert(smallSubview.frame, to: bigSuperview)
```

**I'm trying to convert the small 'Subview' frame, to 'VideoCrop'/bigSuperView coordinate space. Any suggestions? Thank you!**

Comment: Please see my updated answer for clarification on your comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure, but shouldn't you be considering bounds rather than frame of your smallSubView ??

I mean :

```
let rect = smallSubview.convert(smallSubview.bounds, to: bigSuperview)
```

**EDIT**

I could not have answered your comment in answer hence updating my answer :)

The quick view of convert API suggests

> func convert(_ rect: CGRect, to view: UIView?) -> CGRect Description
>   Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of
>   another view.
>
> Parameters
>
> rect   A rectangle specified in the local
>   coordinate system (bounds) of the receiver.
>
> view   The view that is the
>   target of the conversion operation. If view is nil, this method
>   instead converts to window base coordinates. Otherwise, both view and
>   the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow object.

As it suggests you should be considering bounds rather than frame :)

**Whats the difference between frame and bounds then ??**

Bounds : Specifies the views location and size of view in its own coordinate system.
Frame: While this specifies the location and size of view in its superViews coordinate system :)

Hence bounds of any view will have its origin as (0,0) where as frame has its x and y with respect to its superview :) while height and width being same :)

Comment: Smooth. Works! Can you explain why we should use bounds instead of frame? Bounds origin will always be 0,0.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Sandeep! :) Should have read the docs more carefully. Haha. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

##### Apple's convert#to is really silly.

One way to understand it:

Say you want a view named "echo" to be exactly where you are.

```
echo.frame = convert(bounds, to: echo.superview!)
```

*is exactly the same as:*

```
echo.frame = superview!.convert(frame, to: echo.superview!)
```

It's like ...

```
convert(bounds
```

means essentially "your frame in your superview", and that's exactly the same as

```
superview!.convert(frame
```

which also means "your frame in your superview"

### You can always do either of these two things, they're identical:

```
convert(bounds ...

superview!.convert(frame ...
```